# Use variable from the return of other class

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I use the bmi variable from the IMCCalculator.dart class in the interpolation in the main.dart file?

The Person class receives weight and height as required for the calculation:

```
class Person {
  String? name;
  double? weight;
  double? height;
  double? bmi;

  Person({this.name, required this.weight, required this.height, this.bmi});
}
```

I return Person here and want to use that bmi variable to display its value (calculation result) during interpolation on the main.dart file:

```
    import 'models/person.dart';
    
    class IMCCalculator {
    
      static double calculate(Person person) {
        double heightInMeters = person.height! / 100.0;
        return person.weight! / (heightInMeters * heightInMeters);
      }
    
      static Person returnIMCPerson(double height, double weight) {
        double bmi = calculate(Person(height: height, weight: weight));
        return Person(weight: weight, height: height, bmi: bmi);
      }
    }
```

Main file bit of code that I want to change:

```
     Visibility(
                  visible: 
                    _nameController.text.isNotEmpty && 
                    _heightController.text.isNotEmpty && 
                    _weightController.text.isNotEmpty,
                  child: Text(
                    '${_nameController.text}, seu IMC é ${insert bmi value here}',
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleLarge,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                ),
```

Comment: If you're using "Class" to mean "screen", you need to have some sort of communication between the widgets, such as using parameters with a router.  Or you can use some shared state, like Riverpod.

Comment: Look into dependency injection. This will help you create a singleton pattern which will allows you to access a unified state across classes everywhere: https://pub.dev/packages/get_it, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f9XQD5mf6FY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you are wanting to call, returnIMCPerson, is a static method of another class, so you would prefix it with the class name and a period.

```
IMCCalculator.returnIMCPerson
```

That method expects two double's to be passed to it. It looks like you are having users type in a height and weight into text fields that have controllers of _heightController and _weightController.  To get the text from a TextController you would access the "text" field of that controller.  To convert the controller's "text" String you could pass that to double.parse.  So to call that method you would need to use:

```
IMCCalculator.returnIMCPerson( double.parse(_heightController.text),
 double.parse( _weightController.text ))
```

But that function returns a Person class, so to get the bmi value from that result you would need to add .bmi

```
IMCCalculator.returnIMCPerson( double.parse(_heightController.text),
 double.parse( _weightController.text )).bmi
```